# Sonarqube is stopped

Tags: java, windows, elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I want to test my c++ project using sonarqube. When i started sonarqube using StartSonar command, i am getting this problem. So, someone can help me please.I am performing this action on window operating system.

```
C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\temp
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:07 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:07 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\temp --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/common/*;C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.4.199.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\rsharma07\Desktop\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\sonarqube-8.2.0.32929\temp\sq-process17406054299215937266properties
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2020.04.10 13:35:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: What is the content of the `web.log` file?

Comment: @rahul-sharma Did you found any solution for this problem??